# how to match string that containing at least one alphabet and one * in Regex

Tags: regex

I want to match 2~4 length string that containing at least one alphabet and one * by using Regex.

For example, test string is below:

> 124 adbaad aa1 efd **f*ad** *** af 848

(The special syntax of the input will not contain longer similar words, e.g. abc*def)

I want to match **f*ad** in the string.

```
[a-z*]{2,4}
```

I tried above regex but a string without * also matched.

I've searched the Internet for 2 days but I couldn't find solution.

How can I achieve the goal?

Comment: Regexes are not actually good at "in any order". You can tell by the many discussions on password strength checking. Would using a different tool or method be an option? E.g. writing your own "parser" which counts the presence of certain kinds of characters, after splitting by whitespace.

Comment: Hi Yunnosch. Actually I have alternative approach to solve this problem like your suggestion. The reason why I posted a question is.. I want to know whether regex can solve this problem or not. Would it be impossible to solve the problem by using regex?

Comment: Is it mandatory to use regex?

Comment: Would you want the first part of `abc*def` to match? Or not match because in total it is longer?

Comment: @Yunnosch, I think the string abc*def doesn't happen. Thank you for your clarification.

Comment: Consider adding that info to the question. Maybe like "The special syntax of the input will not contain longer similar words, e.g. `abc*def`.". Assuming I understood your comment correctly.

Comment: @Yunnosch, Yup. I added the explanation you said. Thank you for your kindness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the beginning of the pattern, lookahead for 0-3 alphabetical characters followed by a `*`, and also lookahead for 0-3 `*`s followed by an alphabetical character. This ensures that the match starts at a point followed by at least one alphabetical and at least one `*` within the next 4 characters. Then, match `[a-z*]{2,4}`:

```
(?=[a-z]{0,3}\*)(?=\*{0,3}[a-z])[a-z*]{2,4}
```

https://regex101.com/r/90A8rY/1

It's not clear from the question, but if you only want to match standalone words, lookbehind and lookahead for a space (or the edge of the string) at the start and end of the pattern:

```
(?<= |^)(?=[a-z]{0,3}\*)(?=\*{0,3}[a-z])[a-z*]{2,4}(?= |$)
^^^^^^^^                                           ^^^^^^^
```

https://regex101.com/r/90A8rY/3

Comment: Wouldn't that be a total of 1-7 characters? Even before the last part.

Comment: No, because the only part that actually consumes characters is the `[a-z*]{2,4}` - the rest is in a lookahead or another

Comment: I see, I think you are better at the lookarounds than I am. Nevertheless, I recommend to do more explaining to get it across to people like me.

Comment: Works well enough to impress me, but try `abc*def`. Your demo sees and accepts teh `abc*` and I think OP does not want it to.

Comment: Good style how you reacted to me poking at it. And thanks for teaching me about two lookaheads with one consumption...

Comment: Thank you so much all of you guys. I hoped very short magical word but it seems it doesn't exist. :D Anyways I'm very happy to know how regex experts are handling this kind of problems. Now I can sleep well.Thank you again!